# Showing that for $p_k\ \ge 31, p_{k-1}\# > (p_{k+1})^2$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, prime-numbers, primorial

I am trying to show that for $p_k \ge 31,  p_{k-1}\# > (p_{k+1})^2$

Does the following work?  Is there a stronger or more straight forward result that can be shown?

Let:

- $p_k$ be the $k$th prime
- $p\#$ be the [primorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) for $p$.

Base Case:  $7\# = 210 > 13^2 = 169$

Assume that $p_{k-1}\# > (p_{k+1})^2$

If $p_k \ge 31$, there are at least $4$ primes $q$ where $p_{k-1} < q < 2p_{k-1}$ [See [here](http://www.zyymat.com/ramanujans-proof-of-bertrands-postulate.html) for details]

It follows that $p_{k-1} < p_{k+1} < p_{k+2} < p_{k+3} < 2p_{k-1}$

Let $c = p_{k+2} - p_{k+1} < 2p_{k-1} - 2 - p_{k-1} = p_{k-1}-2$

$(p_k-1)(p_{k-1}\#) > (p_{k}-1)(p_{k+1})^2> c(p_{k+1})^2 = c(2p_{k+1}) + c(p_{k+1}-2)(p_{k+1}) > 2cp_{k+1} + c^2$

$p_k\# > (p_{k+1})^2 + 2cp_{k+1}+c^2 = (p_{k+1}+c)^2 = (p_{k+2})^2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution if fine. But you might find this a bit tighter ?

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{k-1} < p_{k+1} < p_{k+2} < p_{k+3} < 2p_{k-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So 
\begin{eqnarray*}
p_{k} \#= p_k p_{k-1} \# >p_k  p_{k+1}^2 > 4p_k^2 > p_{k+2}^2. 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks.  Very straight forward.

Comment: I did not know there are at least $4$ primes between $n$ and $2$ for $n>31$. So, no ... Thank you. $ \ddot \smile$